# sql function with two parameters. Call from VB .NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, function, ado.net

I wrote a sql function which returns a scalar: 1 if the password is correct, 0 otherwise.

```
   CREATE FUNCTION check_credential(  @User_IN nvarchar(50),  @Pwd_IN nvarchar(50)) 
   RETURNS int
   AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @PwdRES int
   DECLARE @PWD_DB varbinary(255)

   IF (@User_IN is not null and @User_IN != '' and @Pwd_IN is not null and @Pwd_IN != '' )
begin
    SELECT  @PWD_DB = password FROM myTable WHERE username = @User_IN
    SET @PwdRES = pwdcompare(@Pwd_IN, @PWD_DB )
end
ELSE
    SET @PwdRES = 0

   RETURN @PwdRES
   END
```

And this works correctly.

I'm using the following code for calling sql function:

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim table As DataTable
    Dim Result As Integer

    conn = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

    sqlcmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    sqlcmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()

    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "check_credential"

    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@username", Utilities.NothingToDBNull(user)))
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@password", Utilities.NothingToDBNull(password)))
```

At this point I want execute the sqlcmd and get the returning value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `function` is different to a `stored procedure`

Either convert your function to a stored procedure or change your command to

```
"select dbo.check_credential(@username, @password)"
```

set the CommandType as `Text` and use `ExecuteScalar`

```
Result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Comment: Is not possible use function?

Comment: @Joseph82 wrap the function inside stored procedure.

Comment: @Joseph82 Why is it so important that it is a function?

Comment: Ok, I changed my command in "select dbo.check_credential(@username, @password)". Now how can I assign the retunring value to the predefined variable (Dim Result As Integer) ?

Comment: @podiluska because there are many function I'm using ...and I can't convert all in procedure

Comment: @podiluska I try with this : Dim result As Integer= sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()   But does not return the correct value

Comment: I tried even with this: Dim flag As Integer = CType(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)

Answer (score 1):

Make @PwdRES an [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) parameter. Also declare the parameter as output in your code and then it will contain the value returned from the function once the command has been executed:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@PwdRES ", SqlDbType.Int)
sqlcmd.Parameters("@PwdRES ").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output)
```

You will need to convert your Function to a Stored Procedure (or add a stored procedure that calls the function) to get it to work I think.

Comment: Take a look at the examples in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/ed8c53cf-9bbd-43e2-81ef-0d5c8b5ed3ff

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an `output` parameter in that case.

In the SQL function:

```
@Value int output,   // Define it in the Parameters
```

Get your calculated value in this parameter say

```
@value = 0
```

Now in the C# code:

```
SqlParameter user = cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.int);
user.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Here you can check whether user is 0 or 1