# Null, Empty or default value for Table Type input of a SQL Function

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a custom table type calls UniqueIdentifierTable

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UniqueidentifierTable] AS TABLE(
   [Value] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NULL
)
```

I have a function that take in this table type as an input:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction](@Input UniqueidentifierTable READONLY) 
RETURN @Output .....
```

I attempt to call this from my .NET layer by passing in a default or empty value.

```
.FromSql("SELECT Output FROM MyFunction(NULL)")
```

The above calls gives me error

> 'Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with UniqueidentifierTable'

Upon googling around, some post suggested that leave it empty then it is a default value so I tried to call the function without any input

```
.FromSql("SELECT Output FROM MyFunction()")
```

I would get the error

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function MyFunction.'

How can I pass in a default empty table value type to this SQL function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql function with two parameters. Call from VB .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384241/sql-function-with-two-parameters-call-from-vb-net)

Comment: Think first. NULL is a scalar value. "Empty" means you are not providing a value for a particular parameter. For the "empty" case, did you provide a default value for your parameter? Nope - then you can't pass "empty" regardless of type. Your function requires a table as a parameter - not a scalar value. One wonders what your function does with an empty table (or a table where any/all rows have a null value) - but that's a different question. So your question boils down to "how to pass a table variable parameter (tvp) to a function". Search on that phrase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing empty list to user defined table type parameter on a scalar function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538527/passing-empty-list-to-user-defined-table-type-parameter-on-a-scalar-function)

Comment: There is no default empty table value type. T-SQL could have added some mechanism or syntax for that, but it chose not to -- you are required to pass in an empty table of the correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comments gave me a lot of information to go on, I'd like to post another approach but from the .net standpoint instead of on SQL server.

I manage to create an empty DataTable and pass it in that way as a parameter.

```cs
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       table.Columns.Add("Value", System.Type.GetType("System.Guid"));

       SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Input ", table);
       param.TypeName = "dbo.UniqueidentifierTable";
       param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

       //some more code to call using context... ect..

       .FromSql("SELECT Output FROM MyFunction({0})", param)
```